# strndup call is currupting stack frames

Tags: c, aix

I have seen a strange behavior with "strndup" call on AIX 5.3 and 6.1.
If I call strndup with size more than the size of actual source string length, then there is a stack corruption after that call.

### Following is the sample code where this issue can come:

```
int main ()
{
    char *dst_str = NULL;
    char src_str[1023] = "sample string";

    dst_str = strndup(src_str, sizeof(src_str));

    free(dst_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody have experienced this behavior?

If yes please let me know.

As per my observation, there must be a patch from OS where this issue got fixed. but i could not get that patch if at all there is any. Please throw some light.

Thanks & Regards,
Thumbeti

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a `#include <string.h>` in your code.  Please try that—I am fairly sure it will work.  The reason is that without the `#include <string.h>`, there is no prototype for `strndup()` in scope, so the compiler assumes that `strndup()` returns an `int`, and takes an unspecified number of parameters.  That is obviously wrong.  (I am assuming you're compiling in POSIX compliant mode, so `strndup()` is available to you.)

For this reason, it is always useful to compile code with warnings enabled.

If your problem persists even after the change, there might be a bug.

*Edit*: Looks like there might be a [problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg06858.html) with `strndup()` on AIX: the problem seems to be in a broken `strnlen()` function on AIX.  If, even after `#include <string.h>` you see the problem, it is likely you're seeing the bug.  A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=AIX+strndup+bug) shows a long list of results about it.

*Edit 2*:

Can you please try the following program and post the results?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char *test1   = "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijk";
     char *test2   = "012345678901234567890123456789";
     char *control = "01234567890123456789012345678";
     char *verify;
     free(strndup(test1, 30));
     verify = strndup(test2, 29); /* shorter then first strndup !!! */
     fprintf(stderr,">%s<\n",verify);
     if (strcmp(control, verify))
         printf("strndup is broken\n");
}
```

(Taken from https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1097#c10.)

*Edit 3*: After seeing your output, which is `>01234567890123456789012345678<`, and with no `strndup is broken`, I don't think your version of AIX has the `strndup` bug.

Most likely you are corrupting memory somewhere (given the fact that the problem only appears in a large program, under certain conditions).  Can you make a small, complete, compilable example that exhibits the stack corruption problem?  Otherwise, you will have to debug your memory allocation/deallocation in your program.  There are many programs to help you do that, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [glibc mcheck](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html), [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/), [electricfence](http://directory.fsf.org/project/ElectricFence/), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Old topic, but I have experienced this issue as well.  A simple test program on AIX 6.1, in conjunction with AIX's MALLOCDEBUG confirms the issue.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     char test[32] = "1234";
     char *newbuf = NULL;

     newbuf = strndup(test, sizeof(test)-1);
}
```

Compile and run the program with buffer overflow detection:

```
~$ gcc -g test_strndup2.c
~$ MALLOCDEBUG=catch_overflow ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now run dbx to analyze the core:

```
~$  dbx ./a.out /var/Corefiles/core.6225952.22190412
Type 'help' for help.
[using memory image in /var/Corefiles/core.6225952.22190412]
reading symbolic information ...

Segmentation fault in strncpy at 0xd0139efc
0xd0139efc (strncpy+0xdc) 9cc50001        stbu   r6,0x1(r5)
(dbx) where
strncpy() at 0xd0139efc
strndup@AF5_3(??, ??) at 0xd03f3f34
main(), line 8 in "test_strndup2.c"
```

Tracing through the instructions in strndup, it appears that it mallocs a buffer that is just large enough to handle the string in s plus a NULL terminator.  However, it will always copy n characters to the new buffer, padding with zeros if necessary, causing a buffer overflow if strlen(s) < n.

```
char* strndup(const char*s, size_t n)
{
    char* newbuf = (char*)malloc(strnlen(s, n) + 1);
    strncpy(newbuf, s, n-1);

    return newbuf;
}
```

Comment: +1: I do not own any AIX SDK to confirm that, but that's a nice bit of digging that seems to diagnose the problem well. You didnt provide a solution or links to any, but at the level of C/C++ it is enough to solve most issues in "my code" (side note: but will not fix any "libraries" that might already use strndup). Anyways, an observation worth a few points! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alok is right. and with the gcc toolchain under glibc, you would need to define _GNU_SOURCE to get the decl of strndup, otherwise it's not decl'd, e.g.:

```
#include <string.h>
...
```

compilo:

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE a.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your prompt responses.
I have tried the given program.

following is the result:

```
bash-2.05b# ./mystrndup3
>01234567890123456789012345678<
```

In my program I have included , still problem is persistent.
Following is the strndup declaration in prepossessed code.

```
extern char * strndup(const char *, size_t);
```

I would like to clarify one thing, with small program I don't get effect of stack corruption. It is consistently appearing in my product which has huge amount of function calls.

Using strndup in the following way solved the problem:

```
dst_str = strndup(src_str, srtlen(src_str));
```

Please note: used strlen instead of sizeof as i need only the valid string.
I am trying to understand why it is happening.

Behavior i am seeing with my product when i use strndup with large size:

1. At the "exit" of main, execution is coring with "illegal instruction"
2. intermittently "Illegal Instruction" in the middle of execution (after strndup call).
3. Corrupt of some allocated memory, which is no where related to strndup.

All these issues are resolved by just modifying the usage of strndup with actual size of source string.

Thanks & Regards,
Thumbeti

Comment: Please don't post questions in the "answers" section, update your original question instead by "edit"ing it.  I have updated my answer, please see that for more information.

Comment: Could it be that your source string is not properly formed and `strndup` is therefore trying to access memory it shouldn't?  Although, for that to happen, you must have a badly formed string in source and huge length in the length argument.